# Django Admin won't work after i changed AUTH_USER_MODEL

Tags: django, django-models

I am trying to make a small authentication app using django, the admin page 
won't work any more, the problem happened after i changed the `AUTH_USER_MODEL` inside **settings.py** , now if i typed `python manage.py createsuperuser` it gives me different fields than it was before, more than that, if i tried to access the admin page, it asks for my phone number as login not username.

Also inside database i can't see any tables that belongs to **auth_user**, in fact, i did the migration but its just recognizing Client model but not Admin model.

Is there any way to make both of my models work ??

Here are my codes:

**settings.py**

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'authiz.Client'
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    'authiz.models.Client',
)
# Login settings
LOGIN_URL = 'login'
LOGOUT_URL = 'index'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'profile'
```

**models.py**

```
class Client(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(null=True, blank=True, unique=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=18,unique=True)
    joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    password = models.CharField(default='', null=False, max_length=255)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'phone'

    objects = UserManager()

    def get_username(self):
        return self.first_name

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.last_name

    def __str__(self):
        return self.phone

    def natural_key(self):
        return (self.get_username(),)

    def set_password(self, raw_password):
        self.password = make_password(raw_password)

    def check_password(self, raw_password):
        def setter(raw_password):
            self.set_password(raw_password)
            self.save(update_fields=["password"])
        return check_password(raw_password, self.password, setter)

    def set_unusable_password(self):
        self.password = make_password(None)

    def has_usable_password(self):
        return is_password_usable(self.password)

    def is_superuser(self):
        return False

    def is_admin(self):
        return False
```

Comment: Django is designed to have a single `AUTH_USER_MODEL`. You can't use the default `User` and custom model `Client` at the same time. Note that the docs warn against [changing `AUTH_USER_MODEL` for an existing project](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/customizing/#changing-to-a-custom-user-model-mid-project). It's very difficult.

Comment: @Alasdair, i meant by all that, is then how to create multi users in django ?? do i have to use sessions ?? sorry, i am new to django !!

Comment: I don’t think you should try to do this, Django is designed to have a single user model. Try to think of a simple custom model that will work for clients and super users, then add additional client information to a profile model.